# Edit the distance to the edge of a paragraph, for one paragraph

Tags: margins, indentation, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs, parindent

What would be the proper way to move the entire paragraph a distance. Not just the indentation.

In the code i show the 2 first lines are good, but when is a paragraph one can see just the indentation was modified. Therefore, \parindent isnt the answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\title{Documento de Prueba}
\author{Martin}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \vspace{18cm}
    
    \section{seccion 3}
    
    
    
    {\setlength{\parindent}{2cm}

    \textbf{One line One line One line One line One line One line}
    
    One line One line One line One line One line One line
    
    \blindtext
    }
    
\end{document}
```

[image: outcome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following suggestion work for you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}


\title{Documento de Prueba}
\author{Martin}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \vspace{18cm}

\section{seccion three}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}\setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \textbf{One line One line One line One line One line One line}

    One line One line One line One line One line One line
    
    \blindtext
\end{adjustwidth}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show part of page layout)

Comment: you just beat me to it and in a more graphic way.

Comment: @Zarko nice command, very stranger i dont found that on any place.
Just a doubt, that command permit use of floats images?. I will try it, thx.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Documento de Prueba}
\author{Martin}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \vspace{18cm}
    
    \section{seccion 3}
    
    \begin{quoting}[leftmargin=5\parindent,rightmargin=0pt]
    \textbf{One line One line One line One line One line One line}
    
    One line One line One line One line One line One line
    
    \blindtext

    \end{quoting}
\end{document}
```

[image]